# How can I highlight the keyword in a search result?

Tags: search, css

How can I highlight the keyword in a search result?

```
{exp:search:results highlight="yes" backspace="5"}
    <p>
        {excerpt}
    </p>
    <br/>                   
{/exp:search:search_results}
```

But highlight is not working..

Answer (score 1):

There is no highlight function with the native EE search module.

You may want to invest in Low Search which is infinitely better http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search

Comment: Thanks for quick response, But I dont want to go with paid one..

Answer (score 0):

Some quick research shows their isn't an easy answer without noodling some complicated PHP, or writing your own extension that hooks in to the search results. By why bother when this might already be solved?

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/search-summary

Try that addon. It hasn't been updated recently, but it got the nod from Derek Hogue, who is a very regular and strong member of this community.l

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a highlight parameter on the [search module](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/search/index.html).

But you can use a [first party add-on](https://github.com/EllisLab/Search-Hilite/) available on EllisLab github account.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if javascript can be an option for you but that should be fairly easy. If you're using jQuery, maybe you can try [this plugin](http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html) .

Comment: If the keywords are in a GET query, this plugin could work. FYI, I wouldn't recommend spending too much time on this user's questions; despite asking several questions and getting good/solving answers in the last 40 days, this person never returns to award the answerer. I hope they change their ways, I'd like to encourage helping!

Comment: Well, let's hope this helps someone else then ?